# Regex to filter out link which does not contain product keyword from a group of links

Tags: regex

I want to filter out the links from a group of links which does not contain a product word by using REGEX. The group of link is delimited by |.

I have the following regex to match with products word.

```
(https:\/\/(?:(?!\|).)*(products)(?:(?!\|).)*.(?=\||$))
```

When I tried to get the list of links which does not contain product word, it is not showing me any result.

```
(https:\/\/(?:(?!\|).)*(^products)(?:(?!\|).)*.(?=\||$))
```

Links are given below.

```
https://cdn.shopify.com/test/|https://cdn.shopify.com/s/products/Profile.jpg|https://cdn.shopify.com/p/products/1Profile.jpg?v=359|https://cdn.shopify.com/s/4/files/products/19front.jpg?v=453|https://cdn.shopify.com/g/p/Chart.jpg?v=1549402459|https://cdn.shopify.com/s/4/products/19back.jpg?v=453
```

Please let me what I am missing? I have tried `!?` and `^`. with the same condition.

https://regex101.com/r/Ynj8ni/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why the pattern does not work*

The pattern that you tried does not match because the first part after matching https:// `https:\/\/(?:(?!\|).)*` matches any char as what is directly on the right is not `|`

That will match until right before the first pipe, and the tries to match products at the start of the string `^products`. But that can not be matched as it starts with `https://`

*A possible solution*

If you want to match the url without products after the first forward slash, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching not a `|` and match a `p` only if what follows is not `orducts` and assert either the end of the string or the next pipe.

```
https?://[^/\r\n]+/[^p|]*(?:p(?!roducts\b)|[^p|\r\n])+(?=\||$)
```

**Explanation**

- `https?://` Match http with optional s
- `[^/\r\n]+/` Match 1+ times any char except `/` or a newline, then match `/`
- `[^p|]*` Match 0+ times any char except `p` or `|`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `p(?!roducts\b)` Match `p`, assert what is directly to the right is not `roducts`
  - `|` or
  - `[^p|\r\n]` Match any char except `p` or `|` or a newline
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times (Or use `++` if possessive quantifiers are supported)
- `(?=\||$)` Assert what is directly to the right is `|` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5gEHT/1/)

If `products` can also not be in the url from the start, so not only after the first forward slash, the pattern can be shortened to:

```
https?://[^p|\r\n]*(?:p(?!roducts)|[^p|\r\n])+(?=\||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5gEHT/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original pattern in fact be correct, one simple way to handle the negative case would be to use a negative lookahead:

```
(https:\/\/(?:(?!\|).)*(?!products)\w*(?:(?!\|).)*.(?=\||$))
```

This is what I believe you were intending to do.  The lookahead `(?!products)` asserts that what follows that exact spot is *not* `products`.  Then, the `\w*` matches any valid word which actually does follow.